# How to filter data from options for special column jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I work with the filtering data in the table, and i create script for filtering data.

But problem is that script filtering data in all table, but i need to filter data only in special rows.

Because i some row i can have same values, and filter will not work properly.

```js
$('#test213').click(function() {
  getSelectedVal()
  filterData()
});

var filters = [];

function getSelectedVal() {
  var startDate = $('#option1 option:selected').text()
  var duetDate = $('#option2 option:selected').text()
  var templateName = $('#option3 option:selected').text()
  var status = $('#option4 option:selected').text()

  applyFilter(startDate)
  applyFilter(duetDate)
  applyFilter(templateName)
  applyFilter(status)
}

function applyFilter(value) {
  if (value)
    filters.push(':contains(' + value + ')')
}


function filterData() {
  if (filters.length > 0) {
    var rows = $("#shelulerData").find("tr").hide();
    var currentFilter = null;
    filters.forEach(filter => {
      if (currentFilter === null) {
        currentFilter = rows.filter(filter)
      } else {
        currentFilter = currentFilter.filter(filter)
      }
    })
    currentFilter.show()
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="option1">
  <option></option>
  <option>Thulasiram.S</option>
  <option>ST Ram</option>
  <option>Ram Kumar.S</option>
  <option>Dinesh Kumar.S </option>
</select>

<select id="option2">
  <option></option>
  <option>11</option>
  <option>21</option>
  <option>30</option>
</select>

<select id="option3">
  <option></option>
  <option>Chess</option>
  <option>Cricket</option>
</select>
<select id="option4">
  <option></option>
  <option>Day</option>
  <option>Month</option>
  <option>Week</option>
</select>
<button id="test213">Add filter</button>
<table id="ticketList">
  <thead>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="shelulerData">
    <tr>
      <th>Fullname</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Sport</th>
      <th>Class </th>
      <th>Term</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="filter-row" data-age="11" data-class="1" data-term="Day">
      <td>Thulasiram.S30</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>Chess</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Day</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="filter-row" data-age="11" data-class="1" data-term="Month">
      <td>ST Ram</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>Cricket</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Month</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="filter-row" data-age="21" data-class="2" data-term="Day">
      <td>Ram Kumar.S 30</td>
      <td>21</td>
      <td>Chess</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Day</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="filter-row" data-age="30" data-class="3" data-term="Week">
      <td>Dinesh Kumar.S</td>
      <td>30</td>
      <td>Chess</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Week</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

So if i will filter for value **30**, which i need to find in row 2, it's will find all values in the table, but i need in just this row.

Answer (score 0):

- You need to know which filter corresponds to which column

  To do this, give each of your columns a `class/id` and pass it to your `applyFilter` function.
- Then search for filter value in that particular column and decide whether that row needs to be shown or not.
  i.e. if the user wants to filter by age, search the age column in the table and show all rows that match the filtered age.

Check out the modified code below.

```js
$('#test213').click(function() {
  getSelectedVal()
  filterData()
});

var filters = [];

function getSelectedVal() {
  var startDate = $('#option1 option:selected').text()
  var duetDate = $('#option2 option:selected').text()
  var templateName = $('#option3 option:selected').text()
  var status = $('#option4 option:selected').text()

  applyFilter(startDate,1)
  applyFilter(duetDate,2)
  applyFilter(templateName,1)
  applyFilter(status,2)
}

function applyFilter(value,id) {
  if (value)
    filters.push('.col'+id+':contains(' + value + ')');
}


function filterData() {
  if (filters.length > 0) {
      var rows = $("#shelulerData").find("tr").hide();

    filters.forEach(filter => {
      $("#shelulerData td"+filter).parent().show();
    })
    
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="option1">
  <option></option>
  <option>Thulasiram.S</option>
  <option>ST Ram</option>
  <option>Ram Kumar.S</option>
  <option>Dinesh Kumar.S </option>
</select>

<select id="option2">
  <option></option>
  <option>11</option>
  <option>21</option>
  <option>30</option>
</select>

<select id="option3">
  <option></option>
  <option>Chess</option>
  <option>Cricket</option>
</select>
<select id="option4">
  <option></option>
  <option>Day</option>
  <option>Month</option>
  <option>Week</option>
</select>
<button id="test213">Add filter</button>
<table id="ticketList">
  <thead>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="shelulerData">
    <tr>
      <th>Fullname</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Sport</th>
      <th>Class </th>
      <th>Term</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="filter-row" data-age="11" data-class="1" data-term="Day">
      <td class="col1">Thulasiram.S30</td>
      <td class="col2">11</td>
      <td>Chess</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Day</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="filter-row" data-age="11" data-class="1" data-term="Month">
      <td class="col1">ST Ram</td>
      <td class="col2">11</td>
      <td>Cricket</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Month</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="filter-row" data-age="21" data-class="2" data-term="Day">
      <td class="col1">Ram Kumar.S 30</td>
      <td class="col2">21</td>
      <td>Chess</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Day</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="filter-row" data-age="30" data-class="3" data-term="Week">
      <td class="col1">Dinesh Kumar.S</td>
      <td class="col2">30</td>
      <td>Chess</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Week</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: For some reason after clicking of button, and chosse more then 1 option filtering is not working

Comment: @Andrew can you explain what you mean by not working?

Comment: When i choose more then 1 filter in one time, i example i wll filter 30, and want to filter by day i will not have this possibility

Comment: var rows = $("#shelulerData").find("tr").hide(); This line selects all rows of the table. If you want the filter to be applied on specific rows, modify the condition to select those specific rows based on id/class name.

Comment: in my case myltiple options filters are working, maybe problem in filterData()

Comment: In your case, it was working because you are filtering only by rows. The code I provided above filters by columns. If you want to filter both rows and columns, you first need to select the specific rows and then filter by columns.